# 2 way binding in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, ionic-framework

Following is my controller of page which user reaches after first page where he enters details of his community and I store in authservice. When user logouts and comes to otp page back from first page, $scope.community is not updated and he still sees old community. What is the mistake I am doing and how can I modify?

```
.controller('OTPCtrl', function ($scope, $state, HOST_NAME, AuthService, Flash) {

  if(AuthService.getCommunity()){
    $scope.community = AuthService.getCommunity();
    $scope.community.face = HOST_NAME + '/community-logo/' + $scope.community.id;
  }

  $scope.login = function (data) {
    AuthService.verifyOTP(data.OTP).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      AuthService.setUserProfile(data);
      $state.go('app.groups')

    }, function (err) {
        var message = 'OTP you entered is not correct';
        Flash.create('danger', message, 'custom-class');
    });
  };
})
```

In the below page none of the values related to community change after loading for the first time. Not even after I logout and come back to this page with changed values in Authservice. I think this is standard behaviour of angular that this controller is initialised only once and not everytime. How do I improve it?

OTP.html

```
<ion-view view-title=
    "<div class='mainTitle'>
     <img class = 'logoBox' src = '{{community.face}}' />
    <span class='insInfo'>{{community.name}} <br />
        {{community.city}} <br />
        {{community.details.phoneNumber}}
    </span>
     </div>">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        //more code
        {{community.name}}

        </ion-nav-bar>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the root cause, but principally I see that you may be mis-using ion-view. Do you intend view-title to contain all that HTML you specified? From the Ionic docs I see

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

this view-title is just supposed to be a simple string. If you want to use HTML in that portion, use ionNavTitle instead

`A text-only title to display on the parent ionNavBar. For an HTML title, such as an image, see ionNavTitle instead.`